# Building a const-correct (C++) library that relies on a non-const-correct library

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I'm building a library in C++ (mostly for fun) that I've been working on for a while now (years, haha, it's just a hobby)

I recently switched some of the underpinnings (read, library dependency) to another library. Unfortunately, said library is not concerned at all with 'const-correctness'. I'm a bit OCD and I like to challenge myself to do things "The Right Way™", so I'd like to make my library const-correct. I've started this a few times, and some parts are; I know that it's better to start const-correct from the beginning but that's not really relevant or up for debate. The fact is that I'm interested in giving it an earnest go again, but the other library prevents me from doing so.

Hows that, you might ask?

Well if I'm calling a method that clearly should be const (doesn't actually change anything), and my method is also a candidate for const-ing (new word), I cannot ensure const-ness on my method until that other method is also const.

**Example:**

```
// Bad third-party library

struct Foo
{
    void should_be_const() {}
};

// My library

struct Bar
{
    Foo my_foo;
    void should_be_const() const
    {
        my_foo.should_be_const(); // ERROR!  Not a const function!
    }
};
```

This is only apparent to me from empirical evidence and from my research and understanding about const-ness. However, this could be a falsely formed understanding so I'm open (and hopeful?) to it being wrong and shown otherwise (although that would shake the foundation of my understanding of const-ness haha)

What's a poor soul to do if he (or she) wants to write a proper library but a dependency isn't written that way?

I hope this is an appropriate question for SO. Please (I'm sure you will) let me know if it's not or if there is a better StackExchange site to post it on.

P.S. I've found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168122/const-correctness-in-c-when-using-a-c-library), but I was hoping the topic/solution could be elaborated on.

Comment: Please show some code, like an example of a poorly designed 3rd-party library function, and how your library uses that library's class.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is one reason for `const_cast`. If you're sure a function really doesn't modify anything (but `mutable` data members), or if you know that an object has not been defined as const, you can cast away the constness. Yes, `const_cast` puts a hole in the type system, so use it with care.

Comment: @dyp that's my understanding of `const_cast` too, but as you say it introduces the need to monitor the declaration of...lots of stuff?  Everything?  It sounds like a nightmare to maintain, and it still wouldn't solve situations where objects _were_ defined as `const`.  Would you agree?

Comment: as @dyp says, `const_cast` is the way to go, unless you're keen on needlessly copying all relevant data (which might be tad inefficient)

Comment: @DrewDormann As I said: You can cast away constness safely in two cases: 1) you know that noone will modify the object. E.g. the original C `strchr` took a `char*` argument. 2) you have a const ref/ptr but you know that the object has not been defined as `const`.

Comment: Ditto on the `const_cast`. Make your library const-correct, and then anytime you dive into a third-party library that isn't, just use `const_cast`.

Comment: Long question - short answer - if an element of a library does not support const, nothing is const (regarding that element). Eg: C# and C++/cli

Comment: @dyp thanks.  Yes, you did say that.  I'm sorry for not being clearer with my question.  What I'm saying is that your "2)" would need to include "you must also make sure, every day until the end of time, that nobody changes those variables to `const`, even if their context makes them look like they could be `const`, as it would introduce UB".  Is that not an issue?

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes of course it is an issue! Sorry for not being more clear. I would consider the first case more likely when interfacing another library: When I know it's going to be changed, I shouldn't take a `const&`. The 2nd case only happens when for some reason *you already have* a `const&` and can't change the interface. That's unlikely for a non-const-correct library AFAICT.

Comment: One thing you might try:  Use your OCD powers to go through the third-party library and make it const-correct, then submit your changes to that library's author as a patch.  (this only works if the third-party library is open-source, and being maintained by people who are open to submissions, of course)

Comment: @all, thanks! I will give some thought to const_cast.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, haha yes. Unfortunately this particular fellow, while quite active and a significant amount of followership around the library, is not particularly concerned with the topic. He generally tosses outside constructive criticism away in a rude fashion. I've considered doing it as a fork semi-privately, but I just don't have the desire to do that when it's not my focus.

Comment: @Volte I've been in a similar situation in the past (where the owner of a third-party library I was using didn't think language-standards compliance was worth his time).  I was able to convince him otherwise by subtly appealing to his ego... I mentioned that while of course it was his library and he could do what he liked, it was also the case that more people would be able to use the library if it was easy for them to get it to work with their code.  YMMV, but I think most authors are at some level motivated by the hope that their work will be popular, so that might be the lever to pull ;)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, you are correct. I like your thinking and I've employed this tactic in the past. Not to sidetrack to what should be left to SE:Philosophy, I feel as if there is a vast majority of programmers exhibit this type of personality. Anyhow, I appreciate the feedback, I will give it my best shot. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The other question you referenced gives a pretty good lead on what the issues are but I'm going to disagree a bit with the answer.  The interfaces in your sub-libraries are going to break into four cases.

1. Things that are not const and cannot be expect to be.
2. Things properly declared const
3. Things that logically should be const, and

   3a. Are implemented as such but are not declared so

   3b. Are not implemented as such

Case 1 is easy - if you want yours to be const, then you need to make a copy of the input before calling that interface.  A cast would be just wrong and will eventually lead to a crash or other error.  Case 2 is not an issues.   So cases 3 it is.

Unfortunately, the reality is that cases 3a and 3b should be treated identically to case 1 because they are indistinguishable.  The implementation could change by platform or version.  So, you should create a copy and then call the interface.  Notice I said "should."  The reality is that most of us will use a const_cast for calling interfaces we think we understand (e.g. strcmp).  It becomes a judgment call about how confident we are in the implementation.  Personally, I wouldn't worry about strcmp.  Pretty much anything higher level could use something like strtok which will break things.